# Show that the nullspace of an operator $A$ is a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

The question I want to answer is

"Show that the nullspace of an operator $A$ is a vector space"

---

This would be easy for me to show if I knew $A$ was a linear operator:

Suppose $x$ is in the nullspace of $A$. Then $Ax = 0$. Therefore $A\alpha x =\alpha A x = 0$ for all scalars $\alpha$.

Furthermore, suppose that $y$ is also in the nullspace of $A$ then $A(x+y) = Ax + Ay = 0 + 0 = 0$

Therefore the nullspace of $A$ is a vector space.

---

What I'm not sure how to do is to show that this is true regardless of the type of operator $A$ is. I don't think it's the case that $A(x+y)=0$ if $A$ is not linear.

What assumptions do I have to make for the question to be valid or am I missing something?

Comment: The statement is not true if $A$ is not linear; simply define $A$ to take some non-vector-space subset of its domain to $0$ (and do something else - who cares what - with the rest of it).  Your proof in the case of a linear operator is correct.

Comment: In linear algebra (so if the questions starts with "show that the nullspace") an operator is assumed to be linear.

Comment: Awesome thanks. Sometimes in the course we talk about operators more generally. I appreciate the insight